# The "this" pointer and containers

Tags: c++, entity-framework, pointers, containers

For my game I have built a small framework which among other things has:

- Entities that own components.
- Systems that hold pointers to the entities.
- An Engine that owns the systems.
- An EntityManager that owns the entities.

Every time I add a Component, the Entity passes it's "this" pointer to the Systems through an Engine pointer that it holds and they decide whether to register it or ignore it.

Now, since the Entities are elements of the EntityManager's container, am I right in assuming that if an insert operation to it causes shifts or reallocation, the systems won't hold valid pointers any more?

If so, what's a good container that can be used to prevent this from happening? If I understand things correctly this is similar to what happens with iterators and the same rules should apply when requiring non-invalidation with insertion.

Comment: If you put those in a vector and use an iterator to store the reference, yes. If you have a vector of pointers nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store a vector of entities and then just store their iterators to access them: yes, a reallocation might invalidate all your data.

The suggested way is to store a vector of pointers (if you need memory collection capabilities you might want to go for a vector of smart pointers). This way you will be sure that the pointers are valid (assuming nothing else touched the objects) at every insertion/deletion regardless of the reallocation of the container's space.

From the question isn't clear but a word of advice if you're just storing objects in your containers instead of pointers: when inserting elements into a container like with

```
std::vector<T>::push_back()
```

**you're storing a copy of the object**. This is usually undesirable since brings additional copy overhead and might create problems if things aren't properly set up. See "shallow copies" and "deep copies" to learn more about this problem.

Comment: I think making the container store unique_ptrs to the Entities is a good idea. This is how the entities handle components anyway. I guess it didn't occur to me at first because I don't need polymorphism in this case. Btw I use emplace_back so copying shouldn't be a problem since the entity constructors are noexcept but thanks for the warning.

Comment: @Veritas storing objects directly even if you use emplace_back shouldn't make you worry about the copy overhead but should still create concerns about reallocations (if you store pointers/references/iterators to them)

Comment: The registering doesn't happen until after I add a component to the allocated entity so that's doesn't matter that much. In any case I'll go with the unique_ptr approach, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer value will only change if a relocation of the actual value happens.
This is the case where you manipulate arrays of objects instead of arrays of pointers to these objects. You should definitely not do the former.

I would suggest using standard collections like std::array or std::vector to manage the objects. With those, and provided you have instanciated the objects on the heap (read: with new), you won't have to worry about the value of this.